# How can I calculate pairwise cosine similarity across multiple vectors in Python?

Tags: python, cosine-similarity, pairwise

For the purposes of keeping it simple I have four vectors --  W, X, Y, Z -- that contain a number of values (each the same length).  I'm trying to calculate cosine similarity across them pairwise in Python, but I can't seem to get the right answer.

If I try comparing W vs. X:

```
print(np.dot(W, X.T)/(np.linalg.norm(W)*np.linalg.norm(X)))
```

I get the following result:

```
[[0.9984622004973391]]
```

If I compare W vs. Y I get:

```
[[0.8891911653057049]]
```

And if I compare W to Z I get:

```
[[0.9676746591879851]]
```

I of course don't want to do these manually one by one, however, as I have many vectors in reality.

When I try to calculate all three (X, Y, Z) vs. W at once:

```
V = pd.concat([X, Y, Z])
print(np.dot(W, V.T)/(np.linalg.norm(W)*np.linalg.norm(V)))
```

I get the following:

```
[[0.9982175434442747 0.005561082504669956 0.020547860729214433]]
```

...where the first nearly matches what I had gotten running them singularly (but still not quite), while the others are way off.

I must have an issue with my approach to the all at once version, but I have not been able to figure out how to fix it.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `np.dot(W, V.T)`, gets three values like

```
[[3.9353 2.4442 2.418 ]]
```

For each value, you must have a different normalization (for `X`, `Y`, `Z`), when you call `np.linalg.norm(V)` you get just one value (norm of **Matrix** `V`). To calculate the norm for each of the vectors (located in each line), you must add the parameter `axis=1`.

Finnaly the correct and short code looks like this:

```py
V = np.concatenate([X, Y, Z])
cos_sim = (W @ V.T)/(np.linalg.norm(W)*np.linalg.norm(V, axis=1))
print(cos_sim)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found `np.dot` to be a bit inflexible, so I opted to use an element-wise multiplication with a sum along the correct axis. For the norm of `v`, you also have to specify the axis or it'll just calculate the norm of the matrix.

```
w, x, y, z = np.random.random((4, 3))

v = np.array([x, y, z])

cos = np.sum(w * v, axis=1) / np.linalg.norm(w) / np.linalg.norm(v, axis=1)

assert cos[0] == np.dot(w, x.T) / np.linalg.norm(w) / np.linalg.norm(x)
assert cos[1] == np.dot(w, y.T) / np.linalg.norm(w) / np.linalg.norm(y)
assert cos[2] == np.dot(w, z.T) / np.linalg.norm(w) / np.linalg.norm(z)
```